# How to create a complex doxygen alias?

Tags: alias, doxygen

I have a situation where I need to nest aliases like this:

```
 /*  \activate{  
 *              \no,
 *              \no,
 *              \no,
 *              \yes
 *              \changes
 *                  - E-mail
 *                  - Is main
 *                  - Home phone
 *                  - Cell phone
 *                  - Relation
 *                  - First Name
 *                  - Last Name,
 *              \no
 *           }
 */
```

See the changes command? It can have inifinite parameters.
How do I work around this issue? This currently looks ugly but less ugly then embedding HTML in my comments.